# How to set "Site Address (URL)" programmatically on WP multisite?

Tags: plugin-development, multisite, options, site-url

I have a new WP multisite configured to use subdomains by default.  Network sites are created programmatically when the user signs up.  I want to give the user the option to enter a custom domain and then update the `Site Address (URL)` for them.

**What is the WP function used to update this field?**

[image]

Comment: Are you looking for [`wp_update_site()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_update_site/)?

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to update that one value, then you can use [`wp_update_site()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_update_site/):

```php
wp_update_site( 123, [
    'domain' => 'new-slug.domain.com',
] );
```

But to really update the site URL/address, you'd need to update both the `siteurl` and `home` options for the site:

```php
switch_to_blog( 123 );
update_option( 'siteurl', 'new URL here' );
update_option( 'home',    'new URL here' );
restore_current_blog();
```

And here's a full working example which does both the above mentioned steps:

```php
$main_net = get_network( get_main_network_id() );
$site_id  = 123; // ID of the site you're updating

// Update the site domain.
$new_domain = 'enter-slug-here' . '.' . preg_replace( '|^www\.|', '', $main_net->domain );
$site_id2   = wp_update_site( $site_id, [
    'domain' => $new_domain,
] );

// And then the site URLs.
if ( $site_id2 && ! is_wp_error( $site_id2 ) ) {
    $details     = get_site( $site_id );
    $new_scheme  = parse_url( get_network_option( $site_id, 'siteurl' ), PHP_URL_SCHEME );
    $url         = $new_scheme . '://' . $new_domain;

    switch_to_blog( $site_id );
    $url = untrailingslashit( esc_url_raw( $new_scheme . '://' . $details->domain . $details->path ) );
    update_option( 'siteurl', $url );
    update_option( 'home',    $url );
    restore_current_blog();
}
```

#### Additional Notes

1. <strike>Make sure the new domain isn't a [reserved word](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_subdirectory_reserved_names/).</strike>

   > **Update Apr 04 2020:** That's actually just for sub-directory Multisite installation.
2. <strike>Make sure the new domain isn't an [existing username](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/username_exists/).</strike>

   > **Update Apr 04 2020:** Please ignore that, I just didn't really notice what
   >   [this](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.3.2/src/wp-admin/network/site-new.php#L119)
   >   is for. And `wp_update_site()` would return an error anyway, if the
   >   domain already exists. :)
3. *This answer is for subdomain Multisite installation only.*

Comment: Wouldn't you use `domain_exists()` to ensure the new domain doesn't already exist?

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of the function and I've just revised the answer. But apart from the additional notes, did the answer/code help?

Comment: I'm not sure yet.  I've been busy building other parts of my site and just wrapped back around to tackle this issue.  I'm now getting "Invalid nonce" when attempting to save any of the plugins I've built, but that could be from a number of other unrelated things.  I'm still sorting through it, but if it works I'll accept your answer.

Comment: Hopefully it works, although I haven't tested on WordPress 5.4.. yet. But take your time! :)